# Redux-toolkit state becomes undefined after performing filter on a empty state array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I just started using Redux-toolkit in my project. One thing I came across is stated in the title.

**Slice Component**

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const followingSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'followings',
    initialState:{
        followings_list: []
    },
    reducers:{
        addFollowing(state, action) {
            const user = action.payload.user
            state.followings_list.push(user)
        },
        removeFollowing(state, action){
            const id = action.payload.user.id_str
            return state.followings_list.filter(following => 
                following.id_str!==id)
        }
    }
})

export const { addFollowing, removeFollowing} = followingSlice.actions

export const selectFollowings = (state) => state.following.followings_list

export default followingSlice.reducer
```

**Store Component**

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import FollowingsReducer from '../reducers/FollowingsSlice'

export default configureStore({
    reducer:{
        following: FollowingsReducer
    }
})
```

Essentially there are two buttons, one is to add an item to the **followings_list**, another one is to remove from it. But if I remove an 'item', even before there is an item in the **followings_list**, my **followings_list** state becomes undefined or at least it disappears from the following reducer?

```
import {useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import{
  removeFollowing,
} from "../reducers/FollowingsSlice";

const dispatch = useDispatch()
// this line is called when the button is clicked, I omit other codes
dispatch(removeFollowing({something}))
```

**Before I called the remove action:**

[image]

**After I called the action**:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi~
Have you already solved it?

I checked your code.
in your ***Slice Component*** code

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const followingSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'followings',
    initialState:{
        followings_list: []
    },
    reducers:{
        addFollowing(state, action) {
            const user = action.payload.user
            state.followings_list.push(user)
        },
        removeFollowing(state, action){
            const id = action.payload.user.id_str
            return state.followings_list.filter(following => 
                following.id_str!==id)
        }
    }
})

export const { addFollowing, removeFollowing} = followingSlice.actions

export const selectFollowings = (state) => state.following.followings_list

export default followingSlice.reducer
```

The part corresponding to the following in the above slice component code

```js
removeFollowing(state, action){
            const id = action.payload.user.id_str
            return state.followings_list.filter(following => 
                following.id_str!==id)
        }
```

Instead of 'return' the filter value right away, you should assign the filtered ***result value to the state***.
You can do it by changing the code like below

```js
removeFollowing(state, action){
            const id = action.payload.user.id_str;
            let filtered = state.followings_list.filter(following => 
                following.id_str!==id);
            
            state.followings_list = filtered;
        }
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: thank you for the suggestion! I was wondering why returning the filtered value is giving me an error?  The first example in [this redux tutorial](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#mutating-and-returning-state) uses the same syntax (and your suggestion uses the second one)?

Comment: Thank you for reply.
createReducer and createSlice have built-in immer library, and immer is a library responsible for managing immutability even if you don't care about immutability.

This is because we no longer need to create and return a new state object from the reducer, and we can change the state directly.

Comment: yes you are right. But if you check the ```todoDeleted``` in the first example from the official link above, they return the filtered value directly which means retuning a new state object is Okay. Thats why I was confused about my codes. Thanks!